# Get Access Token OAuth2 Azure api for FHIR - Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I am using python to insert FHIR jsons into Azure API for FHIR. I have deployed Azure api for fhir service and also did a app registration.

My app is not a web application. It just reads the input json and publishes it to FHIR server. And hence, i created Public/Mobile&Desktop applications.

With postman i am able to successfully post a message. However, i would like to do that with my python script. I am struck at fetching Access Token via OAuth2.

I tried the following code and its throwing empty tenant id . When i googled about OAuth2, There are multiple packages like rauth, ADAL, msal. None of them worked for me.

```
import requests
app_id = <client_id>
token_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token

    token_data = {
    'resource': 'APP_ID_URL',
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'client_id': app_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope':'',
    'username':'USERNAME',  
    'password':'PASSWORD',

    }
```

I am getting 200 response, but it returns an html saying problem signing in the user. Is there a simple way of getting OAuth2 token via python script. I checked other SO posts related to this. Most of the answers are not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking to do is client credentials flow, which you can read more about here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

For Azure API for FHIR, you want to make a service client (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-service-azure-ad-client-app) and once you have a service client, you need to modify your request to something like (not tested):

For v2.0 of the AAD endpoint (recommended):

```
import requests
app_id = <client_id>
token_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

    token_data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': app_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope':'https://<yourfhirservice>.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default',
    }
```

For v1.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) you can probably do something like:

```
import requests
app_id = <client_id>
token_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token

    token_data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': app_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'resource':'https://<yourfhirservice>.azurehealthcareapis.com',
    }
```

Comment: i am able to successfully retrieve the access_token using client_credentials flow. But i am getting 403 - Authentication error while inserting a patient record

Comment: That is probably because the object id of the service principal is not in the list of allowed object ids. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/find-identity-object-ids

Comment: No. i have added the Object id in Authentication section of FHIR Server. Even with postman, when i try  to post Authorization code flow its working. With client Credentials its throwing Authentication Error

Comment: I think you may have added the wrong oid. I have added a detailed answer to your other post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323003/403-authorization-error-oauth2-0-access-token-azure-api-for-fhir

Comment: The v2 scope value ending /.default is key